# is there a way to pull elements hidden behind a drop down menu with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to collect all the plan names on this [page](https://shop.freedommobile.ca/en-CA/plans?sku=190199220645&planSku=Big%20Gig%20Unlimited%2010GB). However, once I collect the list and convert it to text it turns out to be an empty string. Is there a way to collect the info from these elements without having to click the drop down and have element always be in sight?

Therefore, the result should be ['Big Gig Unlimited 10GB', 'Promo Big Gig Unlimited + Talk 11GB', 'Big Gig Unlimited + Talk 15GB',...]

## grabs plan names from one phonelink

```py
planNamesRaw = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gQejUw')))

for element in planNamesRaw:
    planName = str(element.text)
    print(planName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
planNamesRaw = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.sc-bdVaJa.css__AccordionHeader-h99n6k-9.ffctnz')))

for element in planNamesRaw:
    print(element.get_attribute('aria-label'))
```

the name of each plan is in the attribute 'aria-label'